# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> I need to show that $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)\rightarrow0 $  is uniformly in $[0,1]$ (i.e. $\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\,\forall n>N: \|f_n-f\|<\epsilon$)

I tried to find the maximum of $f_n$, because:
$$\|f_n-f\|=\sup_{[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\max\{f_n(x)\}.$$

So if we investigate the maximum value of $f_n(x)$, we get:

$$f_n'(x)=0\Rightarrow x_\max=\dfrac{n}{n+1}.$$

Therefore $\|f_n\|=f_n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$. And here I get stuck. How can I get $\|f_n\|<\epsilon$

Comment: Local extremum + differentiable implies zero derivative. The converse is not true. Is $0$ a maximum of $x^3$ on $[-1,1]$? It only gives you candidates. Studying the variations is safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $\dfrac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\dfrac1{n+1}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\leqslant\dfrac1{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}\times\dfrac{1}{n+1}\to\dfrac{1}{e}\times 0$$

Answer (score 0):

The $f_n$ sequence is decreasing, $[0, 1]$ is compact, constant function is continuous, so the result follows immediately from the [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).